# How to make right-to-left footnotes in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, right-to-left, footnote

If I am using a right-to-left language in Microsoft Word 2010 and want to use footnotes, how do I make the line above the footnotes (dividing them from the main text) also be on the right side?

As in the below picture, I have the right-to-left direction in the footnotes, and the "1" is on the right side, but the dividing line remains on the left side.

[image]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can edit footnote seperators in Draft view.

First, click on **Draft**, which is at the lower right corner.
Go to the References tab and click on **Show Notes**.
In the new window that appears below, open the drop-down menu labeled Footnotes and choose
**Footnote Separator**.
Now you can highlight the separator in the textbox below and align it to the right just like
normal text. Right CTRL + SHIFT is the shortcut I believe.
Now go back to Print Layout view and you should see the changes.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. But when you wrote to choose "Endnote Separator," I think you meant "Footnote Separator" — that's the one that worked for me, and I didn't see a button that said "Endnote Separator" (maybe because I didn't have any endnotes)

Comment: You're welcome, and yes I meant to say footnote separator.

Comment: The "Draft" button is on the "view" tab, under the "views" section group.